# Cannot access to physical HTML file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm migrate my old fashion asp.net MVC application to an angular application.

I've created a subset of .html files that contains templates that will provide the HTML code to build my angular components.

**Problem**

I want to put this html files inside the folder "Views" that already exists on my application. But when I try to access to .html files I receive the following message:

[image]

But if I put the .html files outside this folder I can access directly to them:

[image]

**Questions**

Can you tell me why this is happening?

There is anyway that I can access to html files inside the folder "Views"?

Comment: not unless you add a route to it in MVC and an action which just redirects to that static file, I don't think. Or maybe some sort of HTTP handler. But if you're not using MVC any more it might be easier just to ditch the MVC framework and just put the file in a standard IIS website without all the MVC guff.

Comment: @ADyson I already thought on that, but this application is huge and I need to migrate the architecture step by step. And it will be a period that some of the code it will be on asp.net MVC. But I put this question just to bew aware what is the really problem and some possible solution that can come out.

Comment: Not sure, just putting my 2 cents here, but shouldnt the URL be something like ``http://localhost/[nameofyourwebsite]/Views``. I think (has been some time) you have to register a website/web application in IIS for this to work?!?

Comment: @Rand Rondom No, because I'm debugging in vs 2015 and the website is hosted on localhost:53018 not in a folder of localhost:53018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a long story short, the Views folder is a special folder that holds templates used by actions that are routed by ASP.NET MVC. Because of this, you cannot use it to hold files that are meant to be used directly.

I would suggest ditching the .NET Framework all together since you are going Angular.

If that is not an option or you would like to retain ASP.NET MVC functionality, then simply use another folder (like you have already done by moving the Templates folder to the root).

Comment: I already came to that conclusion, I just wanted to have a second opinion to have sure that this is the problem and the solution is to use another folder to place the templates files

Comment: @RicardoRocha: You asked two questions and I answered them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an explicit ignore in your RouteConfig

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

That should prevent the default routing from taking effect

Comment: It was a good answer but does not solve my problem. The error persists

Comment: Ok - I guess it's because Views is a special folder. A different (`Angular`?) folder would probably work

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, I suggest you take the html markup in your html file and put it on a .cshtml view, that you will render using a GET action in the home controller for instance (as you would normaly do in the MVC pattern).

The other way to achieve this (which I don't recommend), is to add your html file to a deployable folder (like the js folder for javascript files), and than you can call your file using a direct link, however you will lose any capabilities of the MVC pattern this way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not help me because I want to access directly to the html and It is not possible access directly using .cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

As html files are working in views folder, Can you check the path i.e 'Editor/V2/Templates' after 'Views' folder whether it is correct?

Comment: I already check it before I've put the question and it is correct the path